# Excel file path reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

I created an excel spreadsheet with formulas that reference data from another workbook. I shared it with a colleague but when he downloaded it, the excel has a reference to my pathname (highlighted in red). How do I get excel to reference it to his path instead?

[image]

Comment: Use `%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: You can try the CELL() function.